# Revert to previous breakpoint

Tags: matlab

I have a single M file which executes a cascade of 5 functions on an input variable.  Each step takes approximately 1 minute, expect for the 4th one which can take 20 minutes.  I am constantly tinkering with the 4th function to speed it up.  However, each time I run my m file, I have to wait 3 minutes for the first 3 functions to be executed.  Is it possible to set up a breakpoint so that I can keep reverting back to the end of the 3rd step when something goes wrong.

I know that I can save the output of the 3rd function and just create an m file with function 4, but I would prefer not to do this because I want to be constantly changing the input to the cascade.

Comment: use `profile` to find where to optimize your code.

Comment: How can you go back if you keep changing the inputs? it makes no sense...

Comment: Couldn't you just set a breakpoint at the call to the 4th function, run to the breakpoint and then execute the 4th function from the debug command line?

Comment: It's not a coding issue, I am solving a PDE manually and need to find the right tolerances to find the right balance between speed and accuracy.  My 'functions' are not always written in separate files.  They involve combing several external functions within the m file.  The reason for this is that I have about 60 variables being passed back and forth and it is easier to keep everything in one m file.

Comment: I think that you are looking to revert to a *checkpoint* rather than to a *breakpoint*.  To do that you either have to reverse the computation (not theoretically impossible (in most cases) but often practically so) or store the computation's state at the checkpoint.  I don't think that Matlab provides the tools necessary to store the entire state of a computation at a breakpoint (ie checkpoint at the breakpoint).  If you have Matlab running inside a virtual machine I expect you could do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is a workflow that might work for you.

Create a script with cells, delimited by `%%`:

```
%% Specify inputs
in = ['something'];
%% Run function 1
a = f1(in, param1_1, param1_2, param1_n);
%% Run function 2
b = f2(a, param2_1, param2_2, param2_n);
%% Run function 3
c = f3(b, param3_1, param3_2, param3_n);
%% Run function 4
out = f4(c, 0.0001); %0.0001 is the tolerance
```

Now, put your cursor in cell 1 and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute the cell and advance to the next one (there's a toolbar button that does the same thing). Do the same for cells 2 and 3.

When you get to cell 4, select the tolerance (in my example the `0.0001`) in the editor with your cursor.

Press:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Numpad +</kbd> to add 1 to the tolerance and execute the cell
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Numpad -</kbd> to subtract 1 from the tolerance and execute the cell
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Numpad *</kbd> to multiply the tolerance by 0.1 and execute the cell
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Numpad /</kbd> to divide the tolerance by 0.1 and execute the cell

Again, there are toolbar buttons to do the same thing, and toolbar edit boxes to change the increment and factors.

If you need to modify the intermediate variables `a`, `b`, `c` etc, just go back and re-execute one of the earlier cells.